# Como baixar um arquivo com Python?

Tags: python, pdf, download

Este site tem vários links que abrem PDFs, nos locais de "Inteiro teor": 
http://www.camara.gov.br/proposicoesWeb/prop_emendas?idProposicao=2122076&subst=0

Em Python 3 eu escrevi esse código para tentar fazer o download de um link:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
url = "http://www.camara.gov.br/proposicoesWeb/prop_emendas?idProposicao=2122076&subst=0"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "EMC 1-2017 PL678716 =- PL 6787-2016.pdf")
```

Aparece essa mensagem no Jupyter:

> ('EMC 1-2017 PL678716 =- PL 6787-2016.pdf',
>    )
>   )

Baixou um arquivo PDF, mas não abre no Acrobat: não pôde abrir o arquivo porque não há suporte a esse tipo de arquivo ou ele foi danificado

Por favor, alguém sabe como fazer o download correto?

Comment: Sabe dizer se a função `urlretrieve` considera toda a resposta HTTP obtida a partir da URL?

Comment: Não sei dizer se considera

Comment: Consegui solucionar: https://github.com/reichaves/reftrab/blob/master/chupaemenda.ipynb